# jQuery Img toggle Ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two images, when I click on green.png it changes to red.png. But when I load the page and its already set as red.png I need to click the img twice before it changes.I would like to only click once.

```
    $(".page-state").toggle(function(event){
    this.src = "images/red.png";

        var id = event.target.id; //the Div ID variable         
        var dataString = 'page='+ id + '&view=off';         

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pageState.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
        });
        $('#mainFrame')
        .attr('src', $('iframe')
        .attr('src'))

    }, function(event) { 
        this.src = "images/green.png";

        var id = event.target.id; //the Div ID variable         
        var dataString = 'page='+ id + '&view=on';          

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pageState.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
        });
        $('#mainFrame')
        .attr('src', $('iframe')
        .attr('src'))
    });
```

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$(".page-state").click( function() {
    var s = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    if(s[1] == 'red') {
        this.src = 'green.png';
        $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
        // more code for green
    }
    else {
        this.src = 'red.png';
        $(this).removeClass('green').addClass('red');
        // more code for red image
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<img class="page-state red" src="red.png" />
```

As you can see that `.page-state` has class which indicates that what by default, it consists red or blue.

Comment: I’ve tried this already, but this inverses the problem to the green img :)

Comment: I required a mixture of red.png and green.png as defaults

Comment: oh i got it what you want :D wait a min! have you any classes to `.page-state` ?

Comment: yeah i was saying, "Can you add default class corresponding to that image which will be on page load" ?

Comment: Thanks, that works but only if the image is set to red on page load. My php script is setting the img depending if a page is on/off. The img is red if off and green when on.

Comment: Unless I’m missing something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24220/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-afro360)

Comment: We sorted it in the Chat. Thanks for going the extra mile!!